# push to other repo with github action?

Tags: git, github, npm, github-actions

I have several repos that depend on 1 lib repo. For now I'm doing a manual version bump. I can't imagine have to bump to multiple repos in the future when I have more and more repo that depends on my lib.

How can I push to other repos (develop branch), in github action? I did my research, it seems like it only doable in my lib repo, not others.

Answer (score 0):

To push to another repo first you need to clone it. You can do this with the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout/) action. Use the `repository` input to specify the external repo to clone. Additionally, you will need to provide a `token` or `ssh-key` input to be able to push back to the repo (and to clone if it a private repo).

It sounds like you also need to push to a specific non-default branch, so you'll want to specify a `ref` input to checkout the needed branch.

Then, as the next step you can use `run` to run the commands needed to bump your version and then `git add/commit/push` to update the repos.

Comment: can I modify files in github action?

Comment: Yes of course. However you would modify the files from the command line on your machine you can run the same commands on the Github actions runner (provided you are using [pre-installed software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software) or first install the needed software.

Comment: I need to install jq in github action? where does the software hosted in github actions?

Comment: According to the link above JQ is preinstalled on all Github hosted runners. If you are using docker for your action you will need to add it to your dockerfile, but if you are running directly on the runner JQ is already there.